# Moving parameters position in toolbox and combining parameters into one row

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, python-toolbox, parameters

I've been working with ArcGis for a while now and was wondering if there was a way to change positions of parameters inside the toolbox for the user. The only time I have seen this done in arc toolbox is with the Raster clip tool with the Rectangle parameter where the 4 parameters are aligned in a circle in the toolbox.

[image]

I don't know if what I want is possible since I haven't seen anyone else do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that neither Python Toolbox tools nor Python Script tools allow you to configure a tool GUI that provides either indented parameters or more than one parameter per "row" of a tool dialog.

Consequently, you may need to switch from using ArcPy to using ArcObjects if you wish to try and do this.  I am not an ArcObjects developer, and so I make no guarantees about whether they provide this degree of customization.

However, I trust the [comment by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253110/moving-parameters-position-in-toolbox-and-combining-parameters-into-one-row/253112#comment398722_253112) who wrote:

> I can say Yes, if you build a form in ArcObjects you can do a *lot*
>   more things with dialog boxes. Even python GUI with PyWin32 or QT will
>   give more control which may be an easier startup than ArcObjects -
>   unless you intend to learn ArcObjects for other more compelling
>   reasons, in which case it would be a good 'hello world' project.